# Inner join query using multiple values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table structure is as shown:

```
table:App
|AppID|AppName|AppType|
   1    test     new

table:AppRelease
|AppReleaseID|AppID|ReleaseDate|ReleaseVersion|
   1            1   2012-06-20        2.2
   2            1   2012-06-19        2.3
```

I write a query as shown below:

```
SELECT A.*,B.ReleaseDate,B.ReleaseVersion 
FROM App as A 
  LEFT JOIN AppRelease as B ON A.AppID=B.AppID
```

This query is working for single value in AppRelease table, but multiple values in AppRelease table I want to get last added value. Is it possible in single query?

Comment: if you need "last added value" you should try to add in the end - ORDER BY B.ReleaseDate

Comment: Answer added, please tell me whether it works or not. I'm currently adding a sqlfiddle, remembering Sir @FahimParkar previous recommendations...

Comment: @Sebas : I am not Sir, I am just a beginner. :)

Comment: @Sebas : Also you can provide sqlfiddle if table is small or OP has provided inputs. Its easy to understand OP and especially OTHERS.

Comment: unfortunately the sqlfiddle says the having clause is incorrect (unkown column releasedate) which is really unprobable. Adding link for you guys to check

Comment: @Suresh, could you tell if everything is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT aa.*, bb.AppReleaseID, bb.ReleaseDate
FROM App aa LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT a.AppID, a.AppReleaseID, a.ReleaseDate
            FROM AppRelease a INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT AppID, MAX(ReleaseDate) mx FROM AppRelease 
                        GROUP BY AppID
                    ) b ON a.AppID = b.AppID AND a.ReleaseDate = b.mx
        ) bb ON bb.AppID = aa.AppID
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/befa2/3

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/befa2/9 - compare with this.  I removed your innermost having clause, as I'm not sure that makes sense (and mysql was complaining about it).  Doesn't this version work?

Comment: the having would ensure the extracted date was the last one. With your version all are returned, which is wronmg

Comment: hmm, after thinking, the *result* is the same, but the inner calculations *are not*. Many rows are grouped and the max is extracted, being the same each time. In my version, only the rows *with the max* will be returned, which is probably faster. But now I'm not sure of anything anymore...

Comment: are you following me or what? :-)) that's funny I was thinking that I could leave you a message about this one today

Comment: I'm not following you - just keeping tabs on how people are using my site :)  Particularly makes my ears perk up when there may be a problem with it (which I thought might be the case here).  Now I just think that the having clause syntax you're using is simply incorrect.

Comment: I'm not sure of this. If you replace it by HAVING true, it works. Why would it be incorrect?

Comment: It would be incorrect because you are referring to the unaggregated column "releasedate" - having is supposed to only filter aggregate values.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this in a single query you need to obtain the maximum value first in a subquery:

```
SELECT A.*,B.ReleaseDate,B.ReleaseVersion 
FROM App as A 
    LEFT JOIN AppRelease as B ON A.AppID = B.AppI
WHERE B.ReleaseDate = (
    SELECT MAX(ReleaseDate)
    FROM AppRelease
    WHERE AppID = A.AppID GROUP BY AppID
    LIMIT 0, 1
) OR B.ReleaseDate IS NULL;
```

I think there's another way to do this by using the subquery as a join table.

Comment: @Sebas I haven't tested it and at the time of your comment i didn't specify the WHERE/GROUP clauses so it wasn't obtaining the correct values. But aside from that is there another reason it won't work?

Comment: now that you filtered by appid in the subquery, this is one reason less to not work. But still, you are adding an inclusive filter on the table B, which is implicitely turning the left join to an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

Using a JOIN I think the best you can do is select the maximum values from AppRelease.

```
SELECT A.*,MAX(B.ReleaseDate),MAX(B.ReleaseVersion)
FROM App as A
LEFT JOIN AppRelease as B ON A.AppID=B.AppID
GROUP BY A.AppID
```

If you want to semantically get the last-added value, you would probably be better off using subqueries, such as

```
SELECT A.*,
(SELECT B.ReleaseDate FROM AppRelease as B
WHERE B.AppID=A.AppID ORDER BY B.AppReleaseID DESC LIMIT 1)
as ReleaseDate,
(SELECT B.ReleaseVersion FROM AppRelease as
B WHERE B.AppID=A.AppID ORDER BY B.AppReleaseID DESC LIMIT 1)
as ReleaseVersion
FROM App as A
```

Comment: Isn't the second option much less optimized by the db engine?

Comment: I would imagine so, yes. As I said, it's more a matter of semantics. The first query is simpler and gets the job done, but technically it's not getting the last-added value, it's getting the greatest value. They have the same result in Suresh's tables, but that's only because this table structure by design has ever-increasing values.

Comment: What i meant was that subqueries called in JOIN clauses are run exactly once, the ones called in WHERE clauses are called once per row, and those called as COLUMN values are called once per row multiplied by the number of column values constructed via subqueries.